# "Have you got to" vs. "Do you have to"

Tags: sentence-construction, questions, answers

The sentence is:

> I have got to wait for the bus.

Now if my friend wants to ask me about it,
First question is:

What would the question be?

> 1. Have you got to wait for the bus?
> 2. Do you have to wait for the bus?

Second question is:

What would be the answer?

> 1. Yes I have
> 2. Yes I have got
> 3. Yes I do.

I think the word *have got to* is not an auxiliary verb, so I think we need to use the *do* both for the question and for the answer

Comment: Either version of the question is fine. The answer to (1) is "Yes, I have; to (2), "Yes, I do".

Comment: What @KateBunting said. But note that the *full* answers (reflecting in each case the structure of the *question*) are (1) "Yes, I have to wait for the bus" and (2) "Yes, I do have to wait for the bus". From both of which it's perfectly natural to "delete" the final 3 or 4 words because they're ***predictable repetitions*** of a parallel construction. It's also "valid" (but not all that common) to delete the last **5** words from (1), so ***Yes, I have*** is a credible response. But it's at least *non-idiomatic* (probably "ungrammatical", I dunno) to respond to (2) with ***Yes, I do have***.

Comment: Only my personal preference. But i prefer "must" to "have got to" or various forms. Alternatively "need to" if it's a case that something depends on the action. Or "am required to" if it's a law or regulation or some such. But "have got to" sounds very awkward to me.

Comment: @puppetsock Yes, indeed, _have got_ is frowned on, but as it is very commonly used in colloquial speech I didn't want to complicate the issue by correcting it.

Answer (score 1):

The following paragraph applies to my idiolect:

It's "I have to wait for the bus", "Do you have to wait for the bus?" and "Yes, I do". "Have" is not invertible, although there are archaic uses of it being inverted (e.g. "Baa, baa black sheep, have you any wool"). "Have got" is redundant and ungrammatical.

From what I can tell, "have got" is much more prevalent in BrE than AmE.

Comment: Same in my Australian idiolect. However, I would expect to hear “got” in the sentence when particular compulsion needs to be communicated.  “Look I’d love to walk with you, but I’ve GOT TO wait for the bus here or else I’ll never get home in time!”

Answer (score 0):

The answer would 'yes', assuming it's true. Doesn't require anything else.

Dependant upon the context you may want to stress the need to wait :
Do you have to wait (as opposed to walking) - the answer could be emphasised by yes, I do.